# Error while closing form that is running a BackGround Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

First time , i write an application that is running a **foreground**(defult) thread :

```
t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateRandom));
t.Start();
```

And **when i close my form while running thread , it crashes , and throw an exception** .
after some search ([How to close all running threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688923/how-to-close-all-running-threads)), i founded that a foreground thread keeps running after closing main and i have to set my thread to background , so i do somthing like this :

```
t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateRandom));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
```

but it still throwing exception and **i cant close mhy form while running my thread** !!!

And i don't khow WHY ?!

I tried some solutions in **FormClosing event** :

1. Use : `Enviroment.Exit(Enviroment.ExitCode);`
2. Use : `thread.Abort();`

First one doesen't worked , and Second on one crashes when i close form befor running thread .

here is some pictures of my program :

Picture 1 , **Befor closing form** : 
[image: Befor Closing Form]

Picture 2 , **after push the Close Button** :
[image: After Closing Form]

Thank you all .

Comment: in your screenshot error is conversion error it is  because your text value is string you can call Trim on testbox value

Comment: Checking before aborting comes to mind: if (t!= null && t.IsAlive) t.Abort();

Comment: The little `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` in your constructor. What could possibly go wrong? Oh wait, **this** could go wrong

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the exception message `FormatException`. Would have you search with that name you would have got the idea. It has no relation with your running thread. It's occurring cause, the entered text is not a number and thus trying to parse it as `Int` failing with that exception.

Comment: I think this error occurs because UI exited before terminating thread ... is this wrong ?

Comment: @Parsa, NO, as stated in answer it has no relation with UI tread exited or not. You should check what you are inputting in your `textbox3`. it's definitely not a number and so the exception.

Comment: But when i choose little numbers like 100000 it crashes too !

Answer (score 1):

Usually you run your background job **UNTIL** the form is closed.

Something like:

```
void myThreadJob()
{
   while (!IsDisposed)
   {
      // do my "infinite" task until the form is disposed
   }
}
```

Another method is having a boolean field in your form. When your form is closed, set the field to `true` in `FormClosing` event. You then check the boolean field status in the `while` loop in thread code.

Comment: it throw exception again !


An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle().

Comment: Ok. Then try to use the 2nd approach (boolean field, and set its value in form closing to stop the thread)